# mx:MediaPlayback Flex tag

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, mxmlc, mediaplayback

I'm trying to compile `gui/flex/songs.mxml` in the fourth edition of Bruce Eckel's *Thinking in Java* book and am getting a compilation error with Flex 3.4.

Here is a simplified version of the example that gives the same error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
  xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
  backgroundColor="#B9CAD2">
    <mx:MediaPlayback id="songPlayer"
      contentPath=""
      mediaType="MP3"
      height="70"
      width="230"
      controllerPolicy="on"
      autoPlay="false"
      visible="false" />
</mx:Application>
```

Here is the invocation and the error:

```
>mxmlc.exe songs.mxml
Loading configuration file C:\javaTools\flex_sdk_3.4\frameworks\flex-config.xml
C:\songs.mxml(5): 
Error: Could not resolve <mx:MediaPlayback> to a component implementation.

        <mx:MediaPlayback id="songPlayer"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That component is no longer available in flex, i believe since flex 3.0.  There is a video display component built in but you have to set up the controls for it.  If you want a more complete pre-built component you need to import one from flash.  heres a good tutorial from adobe on how to do that - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/video_flex.html